# Capacitor CLI Version Error in Ionic. What to do?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to add android platform to an Ionic (Angular) project.

```
ionic capacitor add android
```

It recognizes ionic capacitor add and requests me to select a platform.

```
? What platform would you like to add? (Use arrow keys)
> android
  ios
```

But as soon as I select the android platform I get this error.

```
? What platform would you like to add? android
[ERROR] Error while getting Capacitor CLI version.

        'capacitor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
```

What is the problem and what do I do? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that you have installed the capacitor?

If not, you can add it using:

npm install @capacitor/core

npm install @capacitor/cli --save-dev

npx cap init

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thnaks above commands are working

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```bash
npm install @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Yarn PnP you might run into this issue because Capacitor will try to inspect the contents of `node_modules` to find out what its version is (and `node_modules` won't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Install @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli globally, it worked for me.

Comment: why do you need to install globally?